# Making Payments using Square SDK Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, square-connect

As I'm trying to make payments using Square SDK from Github (https://github.com/square/SquareRegisterSDK-iOS) I'm not able to find the amount in Square POS App which i have passed from my App.

Please find the below steps which i have actually followed.

1. I have downloaded Square Register SDK from below git hub link.

https://github.com/square/SquareRegisterSDK-iOS

2. I Ran the application using cocoa pods and i have successfully installed the pod file in my project.
3. I have created a test App in my Client login in My Apps Section .

App Name : MyApp

App Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX (My Application Id From Square Dashboard)

4. I have Registered My Bundle Id And Callback Url in Register Api Section

iOS App Bundle IDs: My Bundle Id

iOS App URL Schemes: my Call Back Url

5. As my account is Activated for Receiving payments through applications.
6. Now coming back to my code, i just took Square Register SDK ----> SwiftCharge class methods as it is.
7. Please find the below code what i have used for charge and please do let me know any corrections to be done from my end.

   import SquareRegisterSDK
   import UIKit
   let yourClientID = "xxxxxxxxxx"
   let yourCallbackURL = URL(string: "MyApp://callback")!

   enum Section: Int {
       case amount = 0, supportedTenderTypes, optionalFields, settings

   ```
   init?(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
       self.init(rawValue: indexPath.section)
   }
   ```

   }

   let allTenderTypes: [SCCAPIRequestTenderTypes] = [.card, .cash, .other, .squareGiftCard, .cardOnFile]

   extension String {
       var nilIfEmpty: String? {
           return isEmpty ? nil : self
       }
   }

   class ViewController: UIViewController {

   ```
   var supportedTenderTypes: SCCAPIRequestTenderTypes = .card
   var clearsDefaultFees = false
   var returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment = true

   @IBOutlet weak var currencyField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var amountField: UITextField!

   @IBOutlet weak var notesField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var userInfoStringField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var merchantIDField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var customerIDField: UITextField!


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()

       // Always set the client ID before creating your first API request.
       SCCAPIRequest.setClientID(yourClientID)
   }


   @IBAction func charge(sender: AnyObject) {

       let currencyCodeString = "USD"
       let amountString = "500"

       let amount: SCCMoney
       guard let amountCents = Int(amountString) else {
           showErrorMessage(title: "Invalid Amount", message: "\(amountString) is not a valid amount.")
           return
       }

       do {
           amount = try SCCMoney(amountCents: amountCents, currencyCode: currencyCodeString)
       } catch let error as NSError {
           showErrorMessage(title: "Invalid Amount", error: error)
           return
       }

       let userInfoString = "Radhachandan"
       let merchantID = ""
       let customerID = ""
       let notes = "Sample Test"

       let request: SCCAPIRequest
       do {
           request = try SCCAPIRequest(callbackURL: yourCallbackURL,
                                       amount: amount,
                                       userInfoString: userInfoString,
                                       merchantID: merchantID,
                                       notes: notes,
                                       customerID: customerID,
                                       supportedTenderTypes: supportedTenderTypes,
                                       clearsDefaultFees: clearsDefaultFees,
                                       returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment)
       } catch let error as NSError {
           showErrorMessage(title: "Invalid Amount", error: error)
           return
       }

       do {
           try SCCAPIConnection.perform(request)

       } catch let error as NSError {


   showErrorMessage(title: "Cannot Perform Request", error: error)
           return
       }
      }


   private func showErrorMessage(title: String, error: NSError) {
       showErrorMessage(title: title, message: error.localizedDescription)
   }

   private func showErrorMessage(title: String, message: String) {
       let alertView = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
       alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: nil))
       present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

   }
8. As of now It was redirect to Square Point Of Sale app, but its not displaying the amount what i have passed.

Your kind feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that your amount is getting set properly? Have you tried the example amount code ? `SCCMoney *const amount = [SCCMoney moneyWithAmountCents:100 currencyCode:@"USD" error:NULL];
`

Comment: Yeah i did that but no luck. I'm sure that i have missed something if we can get in touch and review the code it might help me out.

Comment: which amount is being charged? 0.00?

Comment: As there is request call back method for charging amount in square SDK   (SCCAPIRequest) and there I'm passing 500 cents which means $5 technically, when my application is redirecting Square POS app there i was not able to find the amount what i have passed, it is displayed as $ 0.00.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding you. switch over to the Square Point of Sale app, you should see a screen like this http://imgur.com/a/BxRPE . Do you see a screen like that for $5? Could you post a video or some screenshots of what you are seeing?

Comment: When i was redirected to Square Point of sale app, I found a screen one with loading like (file:///Users/macblx/Desktop/IMG_0277.PNG) and after that the screen looks like (file:///Users/macblx/Desktop/IMG_0276.PNG).

Comment: Can you try uploading your photos to a site like imgur? those links don't work.

Comment: When i was redirected to Square Point of sale app, I found a screen one with loading like (http://imgur.com/a/KqWjn) and after that the screen looks like (http://imgur.com/a/XAzTw).

Comment: I noticed that you passed in empty strings for the merchantID and customerID.  Can you try using nil instead? @user2584500

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code like this:

```
...
let userInfoString = "Radhachandan"
    let merchantID = nil
    let customerID = nil
    let notes = "Sample Test"
...
```

You have alerted us of a bug when passing empty strings for these parameters, we will be working on the fix soon.